# diferença entre owl e rdf

Tags: aplicação-web, semântica

estou começando a estudar e trabalhar com web semântica e estou um pouco confuso sobre alguns termos. Gostaria de entender, basicamente, quais as diferenças entre os formatos (tecnologias) **owl** e **rdf**